# How to create a lock with user input on JPanel?

Tags: java, eclipse, jpanel, jbutton

I am a beginner at Java so if there are some simple problems that are in my code please tell me. Thank you in advance!

In Java I have a "login" JPanel which I want the user to enter in a password they like, then have them enter the password on another JPanel (the same password that they created). If it is right and they click the login button again then it would bring them to a screen which says "Welcome" and if they don't, then a screen that says "False. Error". However something on Eclipse is saying that something is wrong and that I can't run it. Please tell me where I went wrong and if you can tell me how to fix it. I would appreciate it!

There are two problems with my code. Both of them are "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody" but every time I add one in, it says "Syntax error on token "}", delete this token"

Here is my code:

```
package Button;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Login {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login Page");
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    placeComponents(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}


private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Pasword");
    userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    panel.add(userLabel);

    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    panel.add(userText);





    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Create");
    loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
    panel.add(loginButton);


@SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner user = new Scanner (System.in);

    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            loginButton.setVisible(false);

            registerButton.setVisible(false);

            userText.setVisible(false);

            userLabel.setVisible(false);

            JTextField userText1 = new JTextField(20);
            userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
            panel.add(userText1);

            JButton loginButton1 = new JButton("Password");
            loginButton1.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
            panel.add(loginButton1);



        });



         loginButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            

                String name = userText.getText();
                String accept = name;
                String good;        

        if (accept.equals(name)) {
            good = "Welcome";

        } else {
            good = "False. Error";
        }               


        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(good);
        label1.setBounds(100, 40, 100, 100);
        label1.setVisible(true);


        panel.add(label1);





        }
       });
}
```

Comment: `" However something on Eclipse is saying that something is wrong and that I can't run it"` -- best for you to post any and all error messages.

Comment: Thank you for the advise! I have tried to post what I have done and what happened.

Comment: Voting to close question as it's little more than a typographical error. I have to wonder if you're getting the cart before the horse -- learn the basics of Java before working on GUI stuff -- you won't regret doing this.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response as well! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
    }

    );
```

Is missing a closing embrace (`}`) - one thing you will learn to do is count brackets and braces

It should look more like

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
    }
});
```

`registerButton` and `loginButton1` are undefined and you seem to be missing closing brace (`}`) at the end of the file as well

I would also highly recommend that you make use of layout managers, they will make life a lot easier for you.  I'd recommend starting with [How to use CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) as it will allow you to switch between multiple views simply

Comment: I have tried doing that, but one problem pops up. "Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement" on this line:   
     loginButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener()

Comment: Then you're doing it wrong. All I did was exactly what I wrote above and it resolved the first issue

Comment: Actually you are aright! The nvm, the problem is fixed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me fix the problem. In the end I was able to fix it and it now works. Here it is:

```
 package Button;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import java.util.Scanner;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class AddOnButton {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Login Page");
    frame.setSize(300, 150);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    frame.add(panel);
    placeComponents(panel);

    frame.setVisible(true);

}


private static void placeComponents(JPanel panel) {

    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel userLabel = new JLabel("Password");
    userLabel.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
    panel.add(userLabel);

    JTextField userText = new JTextField(20);
    userText.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
    panel.add(userText);

    JButton loginButton = new JButton("Create");
    loginButton.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
    panel.add(loginButton);

    String name = userText.getText();

    loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            loginButton.setVisible(false);

            userText.setVisible(false);

            userLabel.setVisible(false);

            JTextField userText1 = new JTextField(20);
            userText1.setBounds(100, 10, 160, 25);
            panel.add(userText1);

            JLabel userLabel1 = new JLabel("Password");
            userLabel1.setBounds(10, 10, 80, 25);
            panel.add(userLabel1);

            JButton loginButton1 = new JButton("Enter");
            loginButton1.setBounds(10, 80, 80, 25);
            panel.add(loginButton1);

            String check = userText1.getText();     

        loginButton1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {           
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {            

            userText1.setVisible(false);

            userLabel1.setVisible(false);

            loginButton1.setVisible(false);

        String good;        

        if (name.equals(check)) {
            good = "Welcome";

        } else {
            good = "False. Error";
        }               


        JLabel label1 = new JLabel(good);
        label1.setBounds(100, 40, 100, 100);
        label1.setVisible(true);


        panel.add(label1);

                }

        });
        }
    });
}
}
```